# Forced unwrapping inside flatMap in combine swift

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am trying to do some forced unwrapping inside my flatMap function but getting following error on return nil line:

> 'nil' requires a contextual type

Following is my code:

```
func fetchOrgs() -> AnyPublisher<[THOrganizationV2?], THError> {
    let locale = userInformationProvider.defaultOrganizationLocale
    let orgID = organizationProvider.currentOrganizationID ?? ""
    
    return thProvider.fetchTHOrgs(locale: locale, orgID: orgID).flatMap { orgs in
        guard let org = orgs.first else {
            return nil// error here
        }
        if org.type == .xpert {
            return self.prepareThURL(with: org, orgID: orgID)
        }
        return THOrganizationV2(serviceURL: URL(string: org.url), type: OrganizationType(rawValue: (org.type)!.rawValue) ?? .aaa, authenticationToken: org.authenticationToken)
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Signature of function called above in thProvider:

```
func fetchTHOrgs(locale: String, orgID: String?) -> AnyPublisher<[thOrganizationEntityV2], THError>
```

I have tried different combinations of map and flatMap but nothing seems to be working for me.

**Edit:**
My goal here is to convert array of thOrganizationEntityV2 to array of THOrganizationV2 and wants to handle forced unwrapping too.

Signature for prepareThURL:

```
private func prepareThURL(with org: THOrganizationEntityV2, orgID: String?) -> THOrganizationV2?
```

Comment: Can you describe, in English, what you want your code to do? Also please show the signature of `prepareThURL`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `compactMap` instead of `flatMap`? Why does your publisher publish an array of optionals?  Shouldn't it just be an array of `THOrganizationV2`?

Comment: Well then why did you declare `fetchOrgs` to return a publisher of `[THOrganizationV2?]` then? Why not `[THOrganizationV2]`, without the optional? Also, you still have not shown the signature of `prepareThURL`.

Comment: I have added the signature for prepareTHURL also I originally wanted it to return publisher of [THOrganizationV2] but to manage force unwrapping I tried this.

Comment: `flatmap` is generally used to flatten an array of arrays. I would normally expect it to apply to a collection type and the closure would output an array of something. It probably doesn't work quite that way in Combine, but the semantics should be similar.  It seems your return type in your closure is  `THOrganizationV2?` so try replacing `flatMap` with `compactMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is looking at the block in the `flatMap` and can't determine what type the `nil` represents.

The `flatMap` operator expects its closure to return a `Publisher` of some sort, not an optional. In your case `flatMap` seems to be the wrong operator. Your code seems like it might be returning `THOrganizationV2?` which is **not** a `Publisher`.

In the block the compiler gets this far:

```
.flatMap { orgs in
    guard let org = orgs.first else { return nil }
```

and says "*hmmm... I'm in a closure that has no declared return type and you're giving me a `nil`.  I don't know what flavor of `nil` that is.  Is it an `Int?`, a `Float?`, a `OmpaLoompa?`... I have no context to figure out what Type that particular `nil` corresponds to.*"

You might fix it by declaring a return type for the closure:

```
.flatMap { orgs -> THOrganizationV2? in
    guard let org = orgs.first else { return nil }
```

or by directly providing a contextual type for the nil:

```
.flatMap { orgs in
    guard let org = orgs.first else { return nil as THOrganizationV2? }
```

But once again, the `flatMap` publisher operator expects the return type to be a publisher.  I don't think your  THOrganizationV2 is a `Publisher`.

Looking at the type signatures in your code, it seems that what you might want is something like this:

```
   return thProvider
     .fetchTHOrgs(locale: locale, orgID: orgID)
     .map { orgs in
        return orgs.map { org -> THOrganizationV2? in
            guard let org = orgs.first else { nil }

            if org.type == .xpert {
                return self.prepareThURL(with: org, orgID: orgID)
            }

            return THOrganizationV2(
              serviceURL: URL(string: org.url), 
              type: OrganizationType(rawValue: (org.type)!.rawValue) ?? .aaa,
              authenticationToken: org.authenticationToken
            )
        }
    }
```

(I typed this into the answer editor, not a compiler so some work may be needed)

I've replaced `flatMap` with `map`.  For each array of `orgs` that come in, the system maps it to an array of `THOrganizationV2?` and those become the output of the publisher so `fetchOrgs` should match it's type signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explaining it in so details